Migrating with T4 Templates to Visual Studio 2022
I am working with an Visual Studio project I took over from a colleague some years ago. Until now it was working well with Visual Studio 2015 / 2017. But now I had to migrate to Visual Studio 2022 on a fresh development machine.
The project is using T4 templates. Now I get errors when I try to run the custom tool (TextTemplatingFileGenerator)
An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Sources\DEV\Source\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0'.
File name: 'D:\Sources\DEV\Source\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0'

In my ttinclude file I have the following:
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0"#>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop "#>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop"#>

I tried several different updates, but don't get it working again. When I change the version number from 10 to 15 in assembly reference then it complains about missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop
Can anyone help me how to migrate?

If you have installed the latest Microsoft.VisualStudio.SDK, you should have Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0 (which should support .NET Framework and .NET 8+)

The latest Visual Studio SDK is installed with the Visual Studio Installer. When I change to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0 I get the error about missing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop

What is the type of your project and which version of the .NET is used?

There is white space "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop "#. Is this a misspelling?
